# Injecting dynamic content inside <head> tag in Nuxt JS Application with data from API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently working on a NUXT application where there is a necessity to add some dynamic content inside `<head>` section of selected pages. The content that needs to get inserted into the pages `<head>` comes from a one time API response when the application initially starts (nuxtServerInit). This will in turn get stored in VUEX.The object structure looks like

```
[{
   pages:['index','home','..',....],
   script:'<script>....</script><script>...</script>,<link href="someCss.css</link>"'
},
{
   pages:['about','..',...],
   script:'<script>....</script><script>...</script>,<link href="someOtherCss.css</link>"'
}]
```

So scripts should be injected/removed into `<head>` section of pages based on the configuration(ie content inside the key **script** should be placed inside `<head>`).
I had a research on this and I found that NUXT provides a head function which can be used inside a **component/layout**, the object returned by that function can be dynamically constructed based on page route name

```
//dynamically generate head scripts based on page route 
head () {
    return getScriptsForThisPage()        
  }
```

But the problem is that the key **script** contains scripts, external links, meta info which should be directly used inside the `<head>` tag. So those parsing logic needs to written inside function getScriptsForThisPage() in order to use NUXT head() function. It would have been convenient if we could directly put whatever inside **script** key to be appended to `<head>` tag.

Is there any better/smarter approach than this

Update - `<head>` should be filled (SEO purpose) before the page is mounted ,so we should not use client side DOM manipulation methods

Comment: is the `script` property just a big string?

Comment: Yes script property contains all scripts, external CSS links, meta info that should be included inside the head tag without any separators

Comment: @Ifaruki I updated the question, please have a look now on the script property

Comment: @KiranMuralee so your script data are a html stream?

Comment: @BekimBacaj script data is the data that needs to be put inside/appended to <head> tag

Comment: is it possible to structure the `script` better? like `script: [{ type: "css", href: "../path"}, { type: "js", src: "../path" }]` ? It would be much easier. If no then it will be harder to filter everything out

Comment: @BekimBacaj@BekimBacaj The data is coming from an API.Problem is in order to use it inside <head> we need to use NUXT head() function but then these data needs to be parsed in order to create that object structure to be used inside NUXT head() function.It would be rather easy if I could directly put whatever data inside script property appended to <head>

Comment: @IfarukiThe data is coming from another API so it would be hard to alter API response to have a better structure.That is the problem

Comment: Please accept an appropriate answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the application is getting data from nuxt server init, what you can do, is store that information as part of the internal nuxt state (say, pass that data via vuex) and update the head based on the page state.
2. Alternatively you can leverage asyncdata (which is used to call a remote API before the page create). This is extremely useful for SSR to dynamically change the data before the page is created. This way you can set the head script based on whatever is set when asyncData has the configuration.

Comment: Yes I agree Ido know I can update the head data using NUXT head() function, but for that I need to separate the scripts, external css, meta info etc (since head function takes in data in a structured format). I am asking if there is an easy way to do it.ie if I could directly put anything inside script property appended to current <head>

Answer (score -1):

Have you aver tried basic DOM techniques such as ::

```
  document.head.appendChild
```

and or ::

```
 document.head.removeChild
```

built in function methods of adding and removing nodes from an existing node or a root element?

That's after you've pre-processed the JSON response and created\parsed the html tags to html elements.

Comment: Cannot use document.head.appendChild here as the <head> should be filled before components are mounted